# Git Publisher Jenkins no push to github but Finished: SUCCESS

Tags: github, jenkins, git-push

I am trying to automatic push a github repo with Git Publisher after build.
After the job is done all task run successfuly even the Git Publisher but there is no push on github.

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1haZ.png)

[Git Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT6AD.png)

[Build steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRrxA.png)

[Git Publisher settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7kEM.png)

Whould you tell me what i am setting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `push` command doesn't actually run. Since you only use Git Publisher to push your commited code to the remote branch, why not get rid of it entirely and just add the `git push` command straight to the build step alongside the `git add .` and `git commit` commands?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, I create a new pipeline job and scripted the solution.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Moi Great, make sure to accept this as the answer if it solved your issue